# Eror message task hung block 120 seccond

Tags: apache2, mysql, nginx

I get an error message on my Ubuntu server 18.04.5 and 20.04.1 and can't run my system.

[image: Screenshot of error]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. You make it impossible for any of us to make a local copy for investigation. Rather, [Edit] your Question, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: Relevant regardless of the process: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181505/what-does-task-mysqldxxx-blocked-for-more-than-120-seconds-mean - sounds like your system doesn't have enough resources for what it needs